# How to get good derivatives results in matlab?

Tags: derivatives, matlab

I got the set of some points, and I need to get derivatives from it. I try to use the `diff()` function in matlab but, well, results kinda not ok. Is there any better way how I can do that?

Comment: Could you describe the type of problems you get? Computing (higher order) symbolic derivatives of multivariable nonlinear expressions is a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

this is only an example, however, before you use the command diff, you have to declare the variable syms x and then derive with respect to x the function you wish :-)